# Write object to flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor

I want to add an object to the flux so that the subscriber will be triggered. This is what I got so far, but write isn't a function:

```
@Controller
class LobbyRSocketController() {

        data class Lobby(val player_1_token: Int, val player_2_token: Int, val game_id: Int) {
@Autowired lateinit var game: Game }

    data class Header(val playerToken: Int)
    val playersInQueue = HashMap<Int, Flux<Int>>()
    val lobbies = ArrayList<Lobby>()

    @MessageMapping("matchmaking")
    fun joinMatchmaking(header: Header): Flux<Int> {
        val playerToken = header.playerToken
        if (playersInQueue.containsKey(playerToken)) return Flux.just(-1)
        val flux = Flux.empty<Int>()
        playersInQueue[playerToken] = flux
        matchmake()
        return flux
    }

    fun matchmake() {
        if (lobbies.size >= 2) {
            val iter = playersInQueue.iterator()
            val gameId = IdGenerator.nextGameId
            val player1 = iter.next()
            val player2 = iter.next()
            lobbies.add(Lobby(player1.key, player2.key, gameId))
            player1.value.write(gameId)
            player2.value.write(gameId)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I will use:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val processor = DirectProcessor.create<Int>().serialize()
    val sink = processor.sink()
    val flux = processor.map { x -> x }

    flux.subscribe({ x: Int -> System.out.println(x)})

    sink.next(1)
    sink.next(2)
    sink.next(5)
}
```